# Modules Error in Prestashop Admin Panel

Tags: prestashop

There is no modules installed line UPS but still getting errors.

Errors:

**Error found : CData section not finished The UPS module can handle the shipping via UPS Ge in must_have_module_list.xml file.

Error found : Premature end of data in tag description line 1 in must_have_module_list.xml file.

Error found : Premature end of data in tag module line 1 in must_have_module_list.xml file.

Error found : Premature end of data in tag modules line 1 in must_have_module_list.xml file.**

Comment: try delete must_have_module_list.xml

Comment: @ethercreation: Thanks Man ! Worked !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try delete `must_have_module_list.xml` (in *xampp/htdocs/prestashop/config/xml/* folder)

Answer (score 6):

The above error occurred in two ways,i.e

1. Error in while login in admin.
   Answer:

   a->Rename your own customize module if you have add any others modules.

   b->Remove two files i.e(`default_country_modules_list.xml`, `must_have_modules_list.xml`) from your  config/xml folder, please make sure backup these two files before removing.
2. Error in Admin panel in module section. Answer: Only Remove two files i.e(`default_country_modules_list.xml`, `must_have_modules_list.xml`) from your  `config/xml` folder,please make sure backup these two files before removing.

I hope above are help full to you.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

Try this

Just rename the below mention both file files:

```
default_country_modules_list.xml
must_have_modules_list.xml
```

and reload the page. Now you can access the admin panel.

Answer (score 3):

I have try my own step, and it's successfull.

1. Open file must_have_module_list.xml (you can find in folder xampp/htdocs/prestashop/config/xml/) by using notepad or other soft to edit code
   note : backup the file before editting, for anticipation.
2. delete texts after code  /modules> (location : in the end of the codes)
3. and then save.
4. I found it's working.
5. Ok, let's try.

Answer (score 1):

That error refers to a dependency of other installed module. Anyway, the problem is a wrong structure of the XML. So, find this XML file inside all your "modules" folder. When you find it (probably inside an old unistalled module) just rename it or delete it.

Good luck

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem , I solved by going to config/xml file

deleted all the files and rebuild the app everything should work :

reference from prestashop docs.

> It would seem an error occurred while those XML files were being downloaded from PrestaShop and they got cut off. Just delete those XML files from the config/xml directory and they should be redownloaded.